# color filter in linux display stack

Tags: x11, colors, display, monitors

is it possible to change the displayed color in a monitor, either in its open-source driver, or other middleware in the display stack of a linux system?

i came across this question because i visited some site which used very bright colors and thus uncomfortable when reading at night but there was no easy way to change the colors in browser (i see there are some color-management addons, but those i tried didnt work well on every site); i think the same problem may also appear in programs other than browsers; so it would be nice if we do some hack on the system instead of a particular application; what i have imagined is a color filter which takes an input color and gives an output color, where users with proper privileges can load different filters in different circumstances;

Comment: try playing with `xgamma` and `xrandr --gamma`. eg. if your output is VGA-0, you can make it sepia/redish with `xrandr --output VGA-0 --gamma 2:1:1`

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to change the gamma on a window/application basis; fwiw, trying to trick it with an embedded X11 server (Xephyr) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @mosvy thank you; not a full-featured color filter but `--gamma 0.1:0.1:0.1` made my monitor a kindle; and there is another `--brightness` option to adjust brightness; much better;